# не получается выполнить задание

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(check) {         
 if (check >= 750)
     check = check - (a * 0.05);
        console.log(parseInt(check));

} 
else if (check < a) {
        console.log(check)

}
```

}[image: вот задание]

Comment: `check = check - (a * 0.05)` — что такое `a`?

Comment: Похоже, что из примера с `parseInt`. 
Должно быть `check -= check  * 0.05;` или `check = check - (check * 0.05)`

Comment: не помогло ....

Comment: `let total = check >= 750 ? parseInt(check *= 0.95) : check`

Comment: @andreymal a - это аргумент функции parseInt(a), просто для пояснения указали

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey только вот этот `a` находится не в пояснении, а в коде, и даже не в `parseInt`

Comment: можете написать в коде ?

Comment: @ТимурИлюхин Это и есть код. Далее, `console.log(total)`

Comment: после первого условия (check >= 750) фигурная скобка отсутствует '{', первую 'a' заменить на 'check', вторую 'a' на 750

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать ответ в виде полного кода ,потому что я так не сильно щас могу сразу понять что куда

Comment: Вообще задание странное. Такое ощущение что и автор задания не знает JS. Предлагать parseInt для получения целой части числа это прямо ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

```js
let check = prompt('Введите сумму:');
let a = check >= 750 ? check - check / 100 * 5 : check;
console.log(parseInt(a));
```